# Как сравнить 2 List и вывести одинаковые элементы

Tags: java, list

Как сравнить 2 List и вывести одинаковые элементы? Пробывал:

```
for (int i = 0; i < compareWith.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < compare.size(); j++) {

                    if (compareWith.get(i) == compare.get(j)) {
                        System.out.println(compareWith.get(i));
                    }

                }
                
            }
```

не работает, выводит только один элемент.

Answer (score 4):

Можете использовать list1.stream().filter(x -> list2.contains(x))

Answer (score 1):

Можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33525962/3212712):

```
new HashSet(original.retainAll(selected))
```

после выполнения в `original` останутся только те элементы, что есть в обоих списках. Надо только помнить, что эта операция может быть небыстрой на больших списках.

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    List<Integer> listFirst = Arrays.asList(1, 14, 14, 2, 5, 6, 9);
    List<Integer> listSecond = Arrays.asList(2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 4, 7, 0);

    getIdenticallyElements(listFirst, listSecond);
}

private static void getIdenticallyElements(List<Integer> listFirst, List<Integer> listSecond){

    List<Integer> elementIdenticallyList = new LinkedList<>();
    elementIdenticallyList.addAll(listFirst);

    elementIdenticallyList.retainAll(listSecond);

    System.out.println(elementIdenticallyList.toString());
}
```